# How to apply a box-shadow to the outside of text with an outline?

Tags: css, text, shadow, outline

I have a block of text that is outlined the way I want. Now I want a shadow effect around that outline. When I apply a box-shadow, it affects the lines, which I don't want. Is there any way to apply to the outer rim only?

https://jsfiddle.net/6nrzkodu/

```
div span{
  font-weight:bold;
  outline: 2px solid green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
}
```

Here is a snippet of the shadowing outside the text I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: your fiddle is empty! please post the relevant code

Comment: My bad: https://jsfiddle.net/6nrzkodu/

Comment: So you want a box-shadow around your outline? We have no idea what your finished product should look like

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't think it can be done easily with just CSS yet. The purpose of the "outline" is for accessibility, such as screen-readers, and are very limited in styling. The box-shadow, as you've seen when applied to inline elements, appears around every line of wrapping text which is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, a box-shadow around the outline.

Answer (score 0):

Just add display:block to your element, so it will still be inline, but now it is a block of element.
You probably want to use `<mark>` instead of `<span>` for that. For HTML semantics and so...
cheers ;)

```
div span{
  font-weight:bold;
  outline: 2px solid green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
  display:inline-block;

}
```

Comment: Yes, but then the text separates from the rest of the paragraph. same as @Austin

Answer (score 0):

So you want one outline around the block?

Try displaying it as an inline-block:

```
div span{
  font-weight:bold;
  outline: 2px solid green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then the text separates from the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: So what exactly is the effect you're looking for? A border wrapped around with the text flow? Do you have an example you are looking for?